# How to solve the equation $\cos(\alpha-c)=a$ for a given pair of numbers $(c,a)$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve the equation $$\cos(\alpha-c)=a$$
where the values of $c$ and $a$ are known, for example:

$$\cos(\alpha - 200^\circ) = -0.49;$$

Could you please explain to me how to find the value of $\alpha$ in degrees?

Thanks for any advice!

Best wishes,
Gendryn

Comment: Do you know about the inverse cosine function?

Comment: $$\begin{align}
& \cos(\alpha - c) = -0.49 \\ {} \\
& \alpha -c  = 2\pi n \pm\arccos(-0.49) \\ {} \\
& \alpha = c+2\pi n \pm \arccos(-0.49)
\end{align}
$$
Is your question about taking the arccosine (or inverse-cosine) function above, or is it about the $2\pi n,$ or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your example:

We have the equation $$\cos(a-200^{\circ})=-0.49.$$

Let $\cos\alpha=0.49\Rightarrow\alpha=\arccos0.49$.  Since we want a negative cosine ratio, we know the angle we want is in quadrant $2$ (given by $180^\circ-\alpha$) or quadrant $3$ (given by $180^\circ+\alpha$).

So we have

$$a-200^\circ=180^\circ-\arccos0.49+360^\circ n\implies a=20^\circ-\arccos0.49+360^\circ n,\ n\in\Bbb Z$$
or
$$a-200^\circ=180^\circ+\arccos0.49+360^\circ n\implies a=20^\circ+\arccos0.49+360^\circ n,\ n\in\Bbb Z$$